# Problema com Html.Partial e ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho meu seguinte controller:

```
public ActionResult Index2(int Id= 0)
{
  if (Id == 0)
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  ViewBag.ClienteId = Id;
  return View();
}
public ActionResult Index3(int Id= 0)
{
  if (Id == 0)
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  ViewBag.ClienteId = Id;
  return View();
}
```

e outros

Em todos eles, eu possuo uma partial com o seguinte código:

```
        @Html.Partial("_MenuInfo")
```

E nele tenho o meu menu com o Id do Cliente, conforme passo pelas ViewBags

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href='@Url.Action("Novo", "Grupo", new { area = "Cadastro" })/@ViewBag.ClienteId' class="btn btn-success">Grupo</a></li>
            <li><a href='@Url.Action("Novo", "Acesso", new { area = "Cadastro" })/@ViewBag.ClienteId' class="btn btn-success">Acesso</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mas acontece que conforme vou navegando nos links

Ele está rendenizando o seguinte link

Grupo/Novo/17/17

Ou seja, está gerando 2 vezes o código do Cliente que vem da ViewBag

Eu preciso que esse menu esteja em várias Views, para que quando eu for dar um "Novo" eu já mande o Id do Cliente que é uma FK na tabela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize:
`@Url.Action("Novo", "Acesso", new { area = "cadastro", id = ViewBag.ClienteId })`

Ao invés de:
`@Url.Action("Novo", "Grupo", new { area = "Cadastro" })/@ViewBag.ClienteId`